# How to set a default boolean for a switch button that was initialized by storyboard

Tags: ios, swift3, boolean, uiswitch

i am facing a problem concerning the default value of the switch button. If the switch button is not used, Xcode gives the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value". I need to set the default value to true or false, if the switch button is not used. I've found some articles about that issue, but they didn't work out for me.

My Switch Button is initialized via the storyboard:

```
@IBAction func FußballPreferenzSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    if (sender.isOn == true) {

        FußballPreferenz = "Ja"
    }else {

        FußballPreferenz = "Nein"
    }
}
```

The following solution didn't worked out for me, because I have no key, or at least I don't know what the key is.

In applicationDidFinishLaunching they advised to write the following code:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let defaultValues : [String : Any] = ["key" : false]
userDefaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)
```

How do I need to change the following code to use it in my purpose? 
Or ist there any other way of solving that issue?

Comment: What does *is not used* mean? You can set a default value directly in Interface Builder.

Comment: It means, that the button was not touched. When the button is not touched, the boolean value of the switch button should be true, so that the variable "FußballPreferenz" is equal = "Ja".

Comment: It's unclear what you are going to accomplish. Do you want to keep the value after switching? Why and when do you get *unexpected found ...* error?

Comment: When I implement the switch button its boolean value is true (the switch button is green). The User can decide with the switch button if he likes soccer (switch button is green/ value=true) or he dislikes it (Button is white/value = false). So if the User opens the view controller, the switch button is green by default. So if he likes soccer he has no need to switch the button. If I now send this information to my firebase console, I get the fatal error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value".

Comment: Set the default value (true) in Interface Builder. The crash occurs most likely because the `IBAction` is not properly connected in IB. If the state of the switch is saved in FireBase you don't need `UserDefaults` but you need to read the value from FireBase and update the switch on application launch (or when the controller is going to be presented). By the way: In Swift you don't need parentheses around an `if` expression and you don't need `== true` after a boolean evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Value of my switch button is set to on. There is just on and off to choose from in the interface builder. But I assume, that it is equivalent to true and false. However it still crashes.

Comment: Check if the selector of the Switch (type valueChanged) is connected to the `IBAction` `FußballPreferenzSwitch`. Select the class containing the IBAction in Interface Builder and control-drag the selector to the switch. In the popup select `value changed`.

Comment: It is connected. It is just strange ...

Comment: And it doesn't work

Comment: (In interface builder) Right click on the view controller that contains the switch, and check if there are any warning signs. Delete the connections that have them. Check also every view in the same view controller in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an `IBOutlet` of your switch, then on `viewDidload` or `viewDidAppear` (which ever you requirement requires)

```
if uiSwitch.isOn {
   FußballPreferenz = "Ja"
} else {
   FußballPreferenz = "Nein"
}
```

This ensures that whatever the default value set on storyboard is reflected on your variable on didload/didappear even if the user did not change the value of switch.

Comment: Cheers mate! That does work. Just one more question. Do you have any idea how to solve the same issue with a segmented control?

Answer (score 0):

Just for it to be here in case someone else (newbie as I was) is searching for a snippet:

On the top of your code (Class definition) add:

```
@IBOutlet weak var switchImageBeingDisplayed: UISwitch!
```

and further down defining the button:

```
@IBAction func switchImageBeingDisplayedChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    if switchLockLanguages.isOn {
        image1.isHidden = true}
    else {
        image2.isHidden = false
    }
}
```